# Using two different contexts - behat.yml

Tags: php, yaml, bdd, behat, gherkin

I want to create two different Context files - FeatureContext.php and ModuleContext.php and use them to run the behat tests (.feature files).

I don't want a huge monolithic FeatureContext.php file; so I am distributing the functions in two files.

In the default FeatureContext.php I have defined some custom functions like:

```
class FeatureContext extends MinkContext{
    /**
    * Wait for site to load
    *
    * @Then /I wait for the site to load$/
    */
    public function iWait(){
        $this->getSession()->wait();
    }
}
```

In ModuleContext.php, I want to call the methods in this manner: ClassName::MethodName (ex: MinkContext::fixStepArgument instead of $this->fixStepArgument) I have defined functions

```
class ModuleContext extends FeatureContext implements Context{
    /**
    * Plugin availability
    *
    * @Then /^"([^"]*)" plugin is available for "([^"]*)"$/
    */
    public function pluginIs AvailableFor(){
        $pluginActivationField = MinkContext::getSession->getPage->find('css selector')->getText()
    }
}
```

Inside behat.yml I have defined the two contexts under the default profile
There are 3 different profiles which denote different testing environments. One of the profile 'prod' has a different password for admin so the FeatureContext and WordPressContext section is repeated under this profile.

```
#behat.yml
default:
    suites:
       default:
           contexts:
               - FeatureContext:
                     parameters:
                         screen_shot_path: 'path to directory'
                         theme_url: ''
                     users:
                         admin:' admin password'
                         local:'local password'

               - WordPressContext:
                     parameters:
                         screen_shot_path: 'path to directory'
                         theme_url: ''
                     users:
                         admin:' admin password'
                         local:'local password'
```

When I try to run a test (.feature file) I get the following error:

Step "/^I wait for the site to load$/" is already defined in ModuleContext::iWaitForTheSiteToLoad()

FeatureContext::iWaitForTheSiteToLoad()
ModuleContext::iWaitForTheSiteToLoad()

I am using PHPStorm. How should I implement two different Contexts?

Thanks!

Comment: Your `ModuleContext` and other contexts beside `FeatureContext` should have `implements Context` and NOT extend  `FeatureContext`

Comment: @lauda I tried that but then I get an error for MinkContext::getSession and other methods of MinkContext saying that non-static method should not be called statically. (ex: MinkContext::fixStepArgument Error-fixStepArgument has protected access).

Comment: I recommend to use page objects for a clean code and better maintenance, please see http://behat-page-object-extension.readthedocs.io/en/stable/